# Android Async task porgress bar doesn't comes until background process is completed

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

I am building a project in which i use async task to show progress bar. 
I am using get() method to wait the main thread so we can do the other task before .

but progress bar is showing after completion of doInBackground thered.
I Want to show the loading bar when the loading starts.
It will dismiss when onPostExecute calls.

```
public class TempConverterActivity extends Activity {   
pojo p;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showResult();    
        }
    });  
}
private void showResult() {         
    try {
        new LoadData().execute().get();                            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("async brix--", e.getMessage());
    }  
    runned();
}
private void runned() {
    ArrayList<String> al = p.getData();
    for (String str : al){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
}
private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(TempConverterActivity.this);
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       dialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
       dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
       dialog.setCancelable(false);
       dialog.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
       if (dialog.isShowing()) {
          dialog.dismiss();      
       }           
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        p = new pojo();
        new SoapParser(p);
        return null;
    }
 }}
```

Please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to display a progress dialog while Sync Process right ?

Comment: Does that mean your dialog box is shown in onpostexecute method?Ad is your background task successful?

Comment: yes my dialogbox is showing in onpostexecute method and background task is also successful and I want to display a dialogbox while sync process

Comment: I think due to get() method it is blocking all other threds to execute simultaniously. It is running one by one.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** In my previous answer I suggested using a Handler; however, AsyncTask eliminates the need to do this which I didn't spot.

Why do you feel the need to call AsyncTask.get()? This is a blocking call, and you call this from the UI thread, thus it is ultimately a race condition as to whether it or onPreExecute() is run first.

I see no reason why you should call get() in this context. You want to call runned() after the AsyncTask completes, but you could do this by launching a new thread from onPostExecute(). Alternatively you could do as you do now, using get(), but call that from a new thread instead of the UI thread.

Comment: I have to call get() because some therads runns parally and one thread in background , ui thread updates itself and it creates a big problem .

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code,

```
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(loginAct,"Process ", "please wait....",true,true);

new Thread ( new Runnable()
{
     public void run()
     {
      // your code goes here
     }
}).start();

 Handler progressHandler = new Handler() 
 {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg1) 
     {
         progDailog.dismiss();
     }
 }
```

Comment: not this code,... however, you need to put your syncing code in run method of mine code....

Comment: ok .. can I put whole class ?? or if i do this then how will i execute the async class